# How to “abort” merge in IntelliJ Idea version 21?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I use `IntelliJ IDEA` the latest version with `Git`.
I have created a new feature-branch and changed some things in the pom.
The same time other colleges worked on master, and they have pushed their changes into master.

I did `merge` my feature-branch to the `master` and `pushed`, and it succeeded. Now because of JDK 11 compatibility problem on Jenkins I should abort my merge which I have already `pushed`.

**Anyone knows how should I revert it in IntelliJ IDE?**

Answer (score 2):

You can't just abort your commit, but you can revert all changes that were provided by your commit. For this, you need in Intellij idea open git log -> select commit that you want to abort -> select option in the drop-down menu `revert commit -> commit changes -> push changes. You will add a commit that reverts your changes